# Where is getConnectionInfo() from NetInfo on React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a strange problem. I want to use getConnectionInfo() from NetInfo API on React Native but, surprise, this method is not here !

Watch the result for a :

> console.log("NetInfo", NetInfo);

```
I/ReactNativeJS(24734): 'NetInfo', { addEventListener: [Function: addEventListener],
I/ReactNativeJS(24734):   removeEventListener: [Function: removeEventListener],
I/ReactNativeJS(24734):   fetch: [Function: fetch],
I/ReactNativeJS(24734):   isConnected:
I/ReactNativeJS(24734):    { addEventListener: [Function: addEventListener],
I/ReactNativeJS(24734):      removeEventListener: [Function: removeEventListener],
I/ReactNativeJS(24734):      fetch: [Function: fetch] },
I/ReactNativeJS(24734):   isConnectionExpensive: [Function: isConnectionExpensive] }
```

If you have an idea...

I use react-native@0.52.2 and this is on Android